# angular2 obj:boolean not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

for some reason my `boolean` doesn't seems to be setting to `true`, it worked in my previous code. Two codes are basically identical therefore the `*ngIf` should turn to true once the `if()` statement is met, the `setTimeout` is working okay.

```html
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" *ngIf="isLoading"></i>
```

Current:

```js
isLoading: boolean;

    login(user){
        var authenticatedUser = users.find(u => u.username === user.username);
        var sessionKey = btoa(user.username);
        if(authenticatedUser && authenticatedUser.password == user.password) {
            this.isLoading = true;
            localStorage.setItem('sessionKey', sessionKey);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            }, 1000);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Previous:

```js
isLoading: boolean;

    loginAction (){
        var uname = this.data.username;
        var pass = this.data.password;

        // dummy session key
        var sessionKey = (btoa(uname) + btoa(pass));

        if(uname=="user1" && pass=="pass1"){
            this.isLoading = true;
            localStorage.setItem('sessionKey', sessionKey);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            }, 1000)
        }...
```

Comment: Any error in the JavaScript console? Do you debug your code to be sure that `this.isLoading = true;` is actually called in your current code?

Comment: odd its returning unidentified, and no console error just debugged it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's returning unidentified"? How / when do you call the `loginAction` method?

Comment: ah it's currently in the service and I moved it to the component where the action of the button is happening.

Comment: Okay ;-) So you mean that it works now?

Comment: Yeah its working now, aha thanks for pointing where its being called.